# Selenium Webdriver xpath to find element

Tags: javascript, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<a style="color:White;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$ctr674$Case$gvCaseSearchDetails','Page$7')">7</a>
```

How to write xpath for the above HTML code in which Page$7 finds the element uniquely and the xpath should find multiple elements through the xpath.
Please do the needful
Thank in Advance :-)

Answer (score 2):

The following code will do the trick

```
//a[contains(@href,'Page$7')]
```

This is your basic XPath expression. You should probably read up on that.